# Is empty interface in golang as function argument is Pass by Value or pointer

Tags: go

If I have function like this

```
func TestMethod ( d interface{} ) {
}
```

If I am calling this as

```
TestMethod("syz")
```

Is this pass by value or pass by pointer ?

Comment: Everything in Go is always passed by value.

Comment: And sometimes that value is a pointer-y thing. :)

Comment: Thanks @flimzy. I was thinking how expensive this operation would be if this is pass by value ( I am new to go )

Comment: Yeah an interface is essentially a pointer to the data and a pointer to the type of the interface

Comment: @Avinash: you can find this out _exactly_, by benchmarking your code.

Comment: A lot is not specified, and specifically, although the actual implementation of `interface{}` is as a `<type,value>` pair—a struct with two members—it's also not specified whether the value part is a *pointer* or a *copy*. For ease of implementation, early compilers have been using pointers. For speed, the compiler probably should copy all "small" or "small-ish" values, and future versions of the compiler probably will do that.

Answer (score 2):

To summarise some of the discussion in the comments and answer the question:

In go everything in Go is passed by value. In this case the value is an interface type, which is represented as a pointer to the data and a pointer to the type of the interface.

This can be verified by running the following snippet (https://play.golang.org/p/9xTsetTDfZq):

```golang
func main() {
    var s string = "syz"
    read(s)
}

//go:noinline
func read(i interface{}) {
    println(i)
}
```

which will return `(0x999c0,0x41a788)`, one pointer to the data and one pointer to the type of interface.

Answer (score -1):

Updated: Answer and comments above are correct. Just a lite bit of extra information.

Some theory

> Passing by reference enables function members, methods, properties,
>   indexers, operators, and constructors to change the value of the
>   parameters and have that change persist in the calling environment.

Little code sniped to check how function calls work in GO for pointers

```golang
package main_test

import (
    "testing"
)

func MyMethod(d interface{}) {
    // assume that we received a pointer to string 
    // here we reassign pointer
    newStr := "bar"
    d = &newStr
}

func TestValueVsReference(t *testing.T) {
    data := "foo"
    dataRef := &data
    // sending poiner to sting into function that reassigns that pointer in its body
    MyMethod(dataRef)
    // check is pointer we sent changed
    if *dataRef != "foo" {
        t.Errorf("want %q, got %q", "bar", *dataRef)
    }
    // no error, our outer pointer was not changed inside function
    // confirms that pointer was sent as value
}
```